# I'm getting unexpected output within media queries

Tags: assets

It outputs the same image, which shouldn't and I am suspicious, that it causing it curly brackets followed after `media queries` and after `twig code`.

```
{% set news = craft.entries.section('news').limit(3) %}
{% for news in news %}
    <style type="text/css">
        @media (min-width: 1200px){
            .hero{
                background-image:url(
                   {% set cover = news.promotionImage %}
                   {% if cover|length %}
                       {{ cover[0].getUrl('gtLg') }}
                   {% endif %});
                 }
        }                       
    </style>
    <a ng-href="{{ news.url }}" flex layout-padding class="promo news {% if news.whiteText %}whiteText{% endif %}">
        <span flex="grow" class="promoText md-headline">
            {{ news.promotionNewsText|ucfirst }}
        </span>
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That works good. Some improvements would be appreciated.

```
{% set news = craft.entries.section('news').limit(3) %}
{% set id = news.uniqueStyleId %}
{% for news in news %}
<style type="text/css">
    @media (min-width: 1200px){
        {% if id|length %}#{{ id }}{% endif %}{
            background-image:url(
               {% set cover = news.promotionImage %}
               {% if cover|length %}
                   {{ cover[0].getUrl('gtLg') }}
               {% endif %});
             }
    }                       
</style>
<a id="{% if id|length %}{{ id }}{% endif %}" ng-href="{{ news.url }}" flex layout-padding class="promo news {% if news.whiteText %}whiteText{% endif %}">
    <span flex="grow" class="promoText md-headline">
        {{ news.promotionNewsText|ucfirst }}
    </span>
</a>
{% endfor %}
```

The reason Why I was getting the same image appeared in my styled block, is because `image` was printed in browser under same class. All I had to do is to set a unique dynamic ID or class.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way. Why are your outputting multiple images for the same background image for the same class.  The last item will override the previous.

```
{% set news = craft.entries.section('news').limit(3) %}
<style type="text/css">
  {% for item in news %}
    @media (min-width: 1200px){
        .hero{
            background-image:url(
               {% set cover = item.promotionImage %}
               {% if cover|length %}
                   {{ cover[0].getUrl('gtLg') }}
               {% endif %}
             );
         }
    } 
  {% endfor %}                      
</style>
```

Comment: I've tried it before either, but it didn't help. Anyway, I've updated the question's code with a part, that may be important to understand it more my situation.

Comment: I have tried the code and get separate images.  Are you saying you get the same image in every iteration? So you have three <style> tags all with the same image being output?

Comment: I've forgot to answer your question.  Every image output in this situation is limited to one only. Done it in control panel. So I'm not getting multiple background images outputs ,therefore I don't get more <style>'s than one.

Comment: Everything is ok except the same image outputs.

Comment: Can you post the code that gets output from the browser developer tools?

Comment: It outputs correctly. But I think I found the bug. See it yourself.